# How to execute multiple java programs in parallel from within a single program

Tags: java, parallel-processing

I have 4 java programs (all are alike), all programs have an infinite loop running in them. Now I want to execute all these programs in parallel from one more program. I want completely independent parallel processing. Is it possible?

Comment: yes. You could use ProcessBuilder and Process.start() to start other program as seperate processes (not threads). Check [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html)

Answer (score 1):

It can be done using MultiThreading.From a single program,U can start your all other four programs as thread.The parallel execution will be there for those totally handled by Thread Scheduler.
Still you can make thread sleep and wait as per your requirement.

"A multithreaded program contains two or more parts that can run concurrently and each part can handle different task at the same time making optimal use of the available resources."